# Use ghostscript to convert PDF to progressive JPEG for web use?

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript on the command line to extract PDF pages as JPEGs.

Is there any switch that I can set in the command to make them progressive JPEGs or do I need to pipe it through ImageMagick or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a progressive JPEG with Ghostscript, it doesn't support that. You will have to use some other tool to do that, I suspect your best bet is to create a TIFF and have ImageMagick convert it.

Answer (score -1):

2022 ...  You can ;)

You convert your `pdf` to `jpeg` and use another lib to convert the resulted `jpeg` to a progressive `jpeg`

Tested with GhostScript v9.55.0 and [jpegtran](https://fossies.org/linux/ghostscript/jpeg/jpegtran.1) and [libjpeg-turbo-official_2.1.4](https://libjpeg-turbo.org)

Once you have your regular JPEG file (file.jpg) you can run:

```
jpegtran -copy none -progressive file.jpg > file-progr.jpg
```

Comment: Ghostscript doesn't use jpegtran. What you are pointing at there is a non-standard build of Ghostscript which apparently does, but it's not the canonical Ghostscript build.

Comment: @KenS, you are right, I have built [GS](https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs9561/ghostscript-9.56.1.tar.gz) from official source with [libjpeg-turbo v2.1.4](https://libjpeg-turbo.org) built separately for my specific needs. I convert `pdf` into `jpeg` using GS, then I use jpegqran to convert the `jpeg` to a progressive `jpeg`.